# Citation Style Language "if then"

Tags: csl

I try to modificate csl style ([Specification](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html)) fore Zotero. I don't know how to do next:
if I have more then 4 authors, I need to insert one text.

How can I do it?
I try next, but it is not work...

```
<else-if type="chapter paper-conference" match="any">
<choose>
    <if variable="name" et-al-min="4">
        <text value="ONE TEXT"/>
    </if>
</choose>
</else-if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of CSL (1.0.1) probably doesn't allow for this, although it's very hard to tell without a concrete example.

The only thing that comes close is that it's possible to redefine the "et-al" and "and others" terms that follow et-al-abbreviated name lists. So if an existing CSL style produces "Smith, Johnson, Williams, Jones, et al.", you could change this to "Smith, Johnson, Williams, Jones, ONE TEXT". It's not clear if that's what you want, though.

(this same question was asked at https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/issues/2092)